# Editing Custom Property in a Pose Bone in Python

Tags: python, scripting, custom-properties

I'm new to scripting.

I'm trying to make a small script that runs after Rigify Generates the rig to do some customization to my rig.

What do I need to write to be able to edit this custom property in a pose bone? (I want to make the max to 7 instead of 6). The info window says: `bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 7` when I change it manually.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/3.0/python_api/#idproperty-ui-data-api

`bpy.data.objects["rig"].pose.bones["upper_arm_parent.R"].id_properties_ui("IK_parent").update(max=8)`